# how to set http version to 1.1 only in wildfly server?

Tags: wildfly, wildfly-10, penetration-testing, penetration-tools

A Issue raised to change HTTP version 1.1 only in web server configuration. 
I am using wildfly 10 as my server.
I have tried using connector varible but it is not allowed in wildfly 10 so help me out with this.

Comment: Is server is using HTTP 2  also ?

Comment: No, currently all request are sent with HTTP 1.1

Comment: Then, what you need to change ?

Comment: If the request goes with 1.0 it should not response i.e. it should be HTTP 1.1 only

Answer (score 0):

In undertow subsystem configuration you should add require-host-http11="true" to your http/http-listener.

for more configuration options see https://wildscribe.github.io/WildFly/13.0/subsystem/undertow/server/http-listener/index.html#attr-require-host-http11